# How to calculate mean date difference with Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table on my postgres database, which has two main fields: **agent_id** and **quoted_at**.

I need to group my data by **agent_id**, and calculate the *mean difference* among all **quoted_at**.

So, for example, if I have the following rows:

```
agent_id | quoted_at
---------+-----------
       1 | 2020-04-02
       1 | 2020-04-04
       1 | 2020-04-05
```

The *mean difference* would be calculated as:

- ( (2020-04-05 - 2020-04-04) + (2020-04-04 - 2020-04-02) ) / 2 = 1.5 days

What I want to see after grouping the info is:

```
agent_id | mean
---------+---------
       1 | 1.5 days
```

I know, by the end, I just need to calculate  (*last* - *first*) / (#_occurrences - 1)
It is just not really clear how (and if) it is possible to do that using a single query on Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `lag()` window function to calculate your differences.  Once you have those differences, use the `avg()` aggregation function.

```
with diffs as (
  select agent_id, quoted_at, 
         quoted_at - lag(quoted_at) over (partition by agent_id
                                              order by quoted_at) as diff_days
    from your_table
)
select agent_id, avg(diff_days) as mean
  from diffs
 where diff_days is not null;
```

The check for `null` `diff_days` is necessary since the `diff_days` for the first record for an agent is null, and you do not want that in the `avg()` aggregation.